# Gaston and Alphonse example: How does the bowBack get accessed?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I have always had trouble with this example. It seems unnecessarily complex way to show the concepts it is trying to:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html

So my question has nothing to do with synchronization or locking; it is probably about anonymous classes:

It is simply how does the code in bowBack which is called in the bow method get accessed? The anonymous class that implements runnable is passed the bow() method.

Maybe this is a bad question. But am I right that illustrating deadlock with anonymous classes introduces complexity into the example that is not needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first anonymous inner class's `run` method calls

```
alphonse.bow(gaston)
```

The `bow` method in turn calls `bower.bowBack(this)` which has the effect of calling

```
gaston.bowBack(alphonse)
```

The second anonymous inner class's `run` method calls

```
gaston.bow(alphonse)
```

which ends up calling

```
alphonse.bowBack(gaston)
```

None of this is very interesting until you take into account that the two `Runnable` instances are being run by different threads and that the `bow` and `bowBack` methods are synchronized. Thus we have a situation where the following occurs:

1. first thread

   - calls `alphonse.bow`, taking the lock on alphonse
   - calls `gaston.bowBack`, taking the lock on gaston
2. second thread

   - calls `gaston.bow`, taking the lock on gaston
   - calls `alphonse.bowBack`, taking the lock on alphonse

Or, more concisely:

1. first thread locks alphonse, then locks gaston
2. second thread locks gaston, then locks alphonse

This easily leads to a situation where the first thread has taken the lock on alphonse and the second thread has taken the lock on gaston, and neither thread can proceed because it's waiting to take a lock held by the other thread. That's the deadlock this example is illustrating.

Now you asked about the anonymous inner classes. An essential point of this is that there are multiple threads interacting over objects and locks. If there were only a single thread, this wouldn't deadlock. How does one get code to run on another thread? The easiest way is to create a thread and pass it an instance of a `Runnable` whose `run` method is executed on the newly created thread. The most concise way to create a `Runnable` (at least prior to Java 8) is to use an anonymous inner class.

An alternative to an anonymous inner class (again, prior to Java 8) would be to use a named class. This would add clutter to the example and I don't think it would make it more understandable. (Then again, I'm quite comfortable with anonymous inner classes.)

A Java 8 alternative would be to use lambdas instead of anonymous inner classes:

```
new Thread(() -> alphonse.bow(gaston)).start();
new Thread(() -> gaston.bow(alphonse)).start();
```

This makes the example quite a bit more concise, though it probably isn't helpful if you are unfamiliar with lambdas.

As it stands, using anonymous inner classes is a reasonable way for this example to get code running on the different threads.

It's hard to think of effective ways to make the example simpler. As it stands, the two threads, two objects, and two method calls have a fairly pleasing symmetry. It would be possible to have the main thread deadlock against a single child thread, but that would break the symmetry. It would also be possible to have the two threads deadlock calling a single method on the different objects. That would make the example shorter, but it would potentially be confusing because that single method would be called **four** times: once on each of two objects, from each of two threads. It might be harder to follow and harder to explain.

Comment: Actually, I have just been reading about lambdas in 8 so this looks like it might help me to better understand the example in that it indeed makes it more concise. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, cool. Lambdas are new enough that it's hard to know that whether using them to explain something will help or make people even *more* confused.

Comment: I think my problem might in part be: I don't understand or at least I have not seen before an object's method being called separately from having a reference to the object itself. But I guess the way anon classes work is that the anon inner class in fact *does* have a reference to the Friend objects instantiated in the outer class. Does this clarify the problem I am having?

Comment: @Jeff Perhaps. The way you're using terminology is imprecise, and that may be a symptom of the difficulty. The `main` method instantiates the `Friend` objects, and references are held in *local variables*. As such, they aren't really "instantiated in the outer class". The `main` method *lexically encloses* the anon classes, which means they have access to local variables defined in the enclosing scope. That's how the anon classes get access to the `Friend` objects. So, the `bow` method calls on the `Friend` objects are indeed called using references to those objects.

Answer (score 1):

The `bow` method calls `bowback`; is that what you mean?  You ask "how does the code in bowback which is called in the bow method get accessed", I'm not sure what else you would mean...

Comment: I mean, how does the anonymous class have access to the bowBack() method? When the anonymous class was created, a reference to the Friend object was not passed in, only to the bow() method. How does it even know bowBack() is a method of Friend? Is this a consequence of the access that anonymous methods have to enclosing classes final variables? (Do you agree that the example for illustrating synchronization is obscured by the way it is implemented?

Comment: The code is within the class Friend, so of course it knows of the methods of friend.  The fact that it is invoking that method on a different *instance* of friend does not change the scope; it is still known to code in the class.  I think the example could be made more clear, yes.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a lot easier to understand when I removed the `bowBack` method and rewrote the `bow` method in this way:

```
public void bow(Friend bower) {
    synchronized (this) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s"
                        + "  has bowed to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        synchronized (bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                            + " has bowed back to me!%n",
                    this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

the basic structure is this:

```
public void bow(Friend bower) {
    synchronized (this) {
        synchronized (bower) {
        }
    }
}
```

So, you get:

```
public void bow(Friend bower) {
    synchronized (alphonse) {
        synchronized (gaston) {
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public void bow(Friend bower) {
    synchronized (gaston) {
        synchronized (alphonse) {
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The black arrows show what waits on what.